# how to create the custom compilation error pages in play2.0 framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to customize my compilation  error message page with my own error message.

How can I do that? Where will the compilation error pages be configured in play 2.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create your own Global object, overload onError(...) and render your own page instead of the default.

Details can be found in the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal)

Given how useful the default error page is, I like to keep those errors while developing and show something more user friendly in production.  As so, I generally do something like:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public Result onError(Http.RequestHeader requestHeader, Throwable throwable) {        
        if (Application.isDevelopment()) {
            return super.onError(requestHeader,throwable);
        }
        // customer facing
        Application.sendErrorEmail("Error occurred on production server: "+throwable.getMessage());
        // give the customer a reasonable message without giving away any internal details
        return internalServerError("Sorry, but an unexpected error occurred.  Please contact the administrator if this error continues.");
    }

    ...
}
```